# Smart Table Sorting of Updated Values

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a Smart Table

```
<table st-table="vm.displayedItems" st-safe-src="vm.items" class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" st-filtered-collection="vm.filteredCollection">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th st-sort="TimeStamp" st-sort-default="reverse">Timestamp</th>
...
```

which has it underlying array updated over time in the following ways:

Item Addition:

> vm.items.push(changedItem);
>   vm.displayedItems = [].concat(vm.item);

Item Update:

> angular.extend(vm.items[count], changedItem);

The table is sorted on the first column but after an item update - the table does not resort itself.

I can see item in the displayedItems array is updated but the table is not. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone provide any help on this?